# Determine if an app needs a network connection in Android

Tags: android, events, networking, wifi

Is it possible on Android to determine if an app is attempting to use either WiFi or data? I.e. Snapchat attempting to check for new messages or the user attempting to send one. Is there an event that I can subscribe to for this?

Comment: There seems to be a number of apps that do this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3493/how-can-i-know-which-apps-are-currently-connecting-to-the-internet Maybe one of this has an API?

Comment: You can't access another app's data, but you can sniff network activity.

Comment: I don't want to access another apps data, I just want to be able to check if an app is requesting a network connection. @AlLelopath I will certainly look into that, thank you!

Comment: Maybe git project https://www.google.com/webhp?source=search_app&gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=git+android+sniffer+network